# 100% height div wrapper expand with 100% height children

Tags: html, css

How do I get a wrapper div that is 100% height to expand its with the height of its children? That are also 100% in height.

The setup looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:100%">
  <div class="child" style="height:100%">div1</div>
  <div class="child" style="height:100%">div2</div>
</div>
```

But the wrapper dosen't expand to 200% height. I have tried making the wrapper `min-height:100%;` but then the children don't inherit the full height, only the height of their own content.

https://jsfiddle.net/on78pof8/

(The aqua colored box, dosen't expand)

Comment: I think you have forgotten to specify the width of the `child`. Set `width:100%;` to the child.

Comment: All it needs is `overflow: auto;` on the parent. See snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set height in viewport units on the child divs

```
.child {
  height:100vh;
}
```

### [Demo (with viewport units)](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/on78pof8/10/)

(NB: The OP is actually interested in background image on the wrapper instead of the solid aqua color)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  background: aqua;
}
.child {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="child">div1</div>

  <div class="child">div2</div>

</div>
```

---

If you don't want to use viewport units (which by the way - as @CoadToad pointed out in the comments - has [very good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)) - then I think you'll have to use javascript.

### [Demo (with javascript)](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/on78pof8/11/)

Comment: That is what i want to achieve. However i would prefer not to use 'vh' but a more widely supported method.

Comment: vh is widely supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units  are you trying to support internet explorer versions 8 and below? that's close to 1% market share.

Comment: @Danield unfortunately that won't work. It looks right in this example, but it won't work in this case.

Comment: Could you post an example which demonstrates that it's not working or at least explain why?

Comment: @Danield if i have a background image on the wrapper instead of a solid color.

Answer (score 4):

Please tell me if I didn't understand the question correctly.
I think you have forgotten to add `width:100%;` to the child divs.

To remove the extra scroll bar on the html/body, you can remove the default margin/padding of html and body by using this declaration:

```
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Here is what I believe you have in mind:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
  background: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="child">div1</div>

  <div class="child">div2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a dynamic number for the height of the child divs, depending on your needs, you can set these from the view-port height (vw) but this assumes you want them each to be the full height of the entire document.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `overflow-y: auto` on the parent for this to work. Here:

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  background:aqua;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  
  <div class="child">div2</div>

</div>
```